# Selecting data so that it only returns the latest row per ID

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm currently working on my first Laravel project and I'm working with a database that has rows like this:

```
id       message    timestamp

1        first      1500000000 
1        second     1510000000
1        third      1520000000
1        fourth     1530000000
2        first      1500000000 
2        second     1510000000 
3        first      1500000000 
4        first      1500000000 
4        second     1510000000  
4        third      1520000000 
4        fourth     1530000000 
5        first      1500000000 
5        second     1510000000 
6        first      1500000000 
7        first      1500000000
```

(dummy data). I want to make an SQL query that returns the latest message based on the highest timestamp. So for example if we take a look at the first id I want it to return `fourth` because the timestamp connected to that message is higher than any other record with `id = 1`.

The reason I want to have only 1 query for every id is because the more queries I have to run the longer it takes to run the page, making the user-experience pretty poor.

I've tried several things that I've read online, but to no avail. I've tried using `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` and some question built queries I came across. I've taken a look at the Laravel documentation as well but I just can't get it to work.

```
$data = \DB::table('data')
         ->distinct()
         ->get();
```

Tried things like this but now that I think of it this probably just returns the unique combinations of id, message and timestamp.

In the end I'd like to get something like this:

```
id       message    timestamp

1        fourth     1530000000
2        second     1510000000 
3        first      1500000000 
4        fourth     1530000000 
5        second     1510000000 
6        first      1500000000 
7        first      1500000000
```

Anyway I would really appreciate it if someone knows how to solve my problem.

P.S. For some reason every query I execute takes about 2s to return data (saw this in the Laravel Debugger extension). Could this be caused by the large amount of records in the table (3926714)? And does someone maybe know how to reduce the amount of time it takes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to group by id then order by time stamp. Then get the message

```
\DB::table('data')->groupBy('id')->orderBy('timestamp')->first()->message
```

Edit: If your table is huge and is growing drastically, and you only need the message, try to execute it via raw SQL instead of using eloquent for fast performance.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use your code. ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'BootLogging.ycl_loggingdata.idlog' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `ycl_loggingdata` group by `idobject` order by `timestampsec` asc limit 1)```. Don't know if it is relevant but the table has more columns than the 3 I listed above. The three I listed are the only relevant ones though.

Comment: update the MySQL settings on config > database.php, then adjust the MySQL strict to `'strict' => false`

Comment: Just did that, it worked! however it seems to take 21 seconds before I have my data, both with the Eloquent way as well as the raw SQL way. Do you know of a way to decrease how long it takes?

Comment: I can't say anything on this without seeing your SQL query.

Comment: The query is ```\DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT idobject, message, timestampsec
                                    FROM ycl_loggingdata
                                    GROUP BY idobject'));``` This took 22.4s (http://prntscr.com/nxu2mj)

Comment: Your query seems incorrect, this is not going to give the response as per in your question, neither my answer is no way related to your sql query.

Comment: Adding a where significantly decreased the time it took so that's good. Only problem is that it still took 3s and I have to do 3 of these queries so that will still be very slow. ```SELECT idobject, message, timestampsec
FROM ycl_loggingdata
WHERE idlogdefinitie = 2
GROUP BY idobject``` is what i have right now. Do you think indexing the database would speed things up?

Comment: Your query returned only one row, I stated I required a row for every ID. As for the orderby, it wasn't really relevant since I'm just looping through the records and not actually printing them like that.

Comment: create a room and invite to chat, will share the details there.

Comment: Apparently I can't create rooms yet, need 100 reputation for that.

Comment: Can you create a room?

Comment: Alright so I've almost nailed it down to the result I want. This is the query I have right now http://prntscr.com/nxvz71 . The thing is, the record that it returns has the lowest timestampsec, and I want it to be the highest. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this: DB::table('your-table')->orderby('id',DESC)->orderby('message',ASC)->get();

Comment: I forgot. You can aswell add distinct to to the query to get the distinct id

Comment: This approach exceeded the 60 second period so I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way.

Comment: In that case you can work on your table so you can implement relations. I think with that I will be fast

Answer (score 0):

Self JOIN

```
 $sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM data t1 JOIN ( SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) as max_created FROM data GROUP BY id ) t2 ON t1.`id` = t2.`id` AND t1.`timestamp` = t2.`max_created`";

 $rows= DB::select($sql);
 dd($rows);
```